# xlrd invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlrd

I need parse an cell which contains data format 'Tuesday, January 3, 2012 2:46pm'. The code below gives error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Tuesday, January 3, 2012 2:46pm'
```

May I know what is the right way to parse this string into datetime?

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(f)
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for rx in range(1, 10):  #sh.nrows
    m = sh.row(rx)
    print datetime(xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(m[0].value, book.datemode))
```

---

Traceback

```
File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\xlrd\xldate.py", line 67, in xldate_as_tuple
    xldays = int(xldate)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Tuesday, January 3, 2012 2:46pm'
```

Comment: Can you paste the full traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I do not think `m[0]` has an `xldate` value, looks like it is coming as string.

@Sait's answer is good. But if you do not want to use dateutil , you can use `datetime.datetime.strptime()` function like this -

```
datetime.strptime('Tuesday, January 3, 2012 2:46pm', '%A, %B %d, %Y %H:%M%p')
```

In your case -

```
print datetime.strptime(m[0].value, '%A, %B %d, %Y %H:%M%p')
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
In [8]: from dateutil import parser

In [9]: dt = parser.parse('Tuesday, January 3, 2012 2:46pm')

In [10]: print dt
2012-01-03 14:46:00
```